# User-level threads context switching: How to detect when a thread is blocking in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, multitasking

As the title suggests, is there a way in C to detect when a user-level thread running on top of a kernel-level thread e.g., pthread has blocked (or about to block) for I/O?

My use case is as follows: I need to execute tasks in a multithreaded environment (on top of kernel threads e.g., pthreads). The tasks are basically user functions that can be synchronized and may use blocking operations within. I need to hide latency in my implementation. So, I am exploring the idea of implementing the tasks as user-level threads for better control of their execution context such that, when a task blocks or synchronizes, I context-switch to other ready tasks (i.e., implementing my own scheduler for the user-level threads). Consequently, almost the full use of the OS’s time quantum per kernel thread can be achieved.

Comment: Something like Many-to-Many thread design? There is Many to One, Many-to Many and Hybrid model or One-to-One.

Comment: I could have 1 or more kernel-level threads executing user-level threads. So, yes it is N:M.

Comment: What do you think "blocked" means?

Comment: @kfsone Am I missing something here? Do you mean, because it is block, there is no means to detect that?

Comment: @TuaimiAA That it's blocked - typically suspended by the kernel. pthread_mutex_lock, for instance, guarantees that it *will not* return EINTR. So if a thread is blocked on a mutex, it's blocked. If a thread is blocked on a read operation, your choices are to wait for the kernel to signal that data is ready or to *interrupt* the read, which means that the calling code will have to re-call `read`. But I'm also questioning whether you are worrying about something that has been stopped for a long time vs something that has been suspended e.g for a linked operation in another thread.

Comment: @TuaimiAA Consider: how would it be possible to get this information accurately? Lets say you call `ret = pthread_imaginary_status(threadId)`. How will you know how accurate (decayed) the information is? If ret tells us the thread is blocked, the kernel could easily have unblocked the thread at literally the same instant as your thread queried the value, but didn't commit the update until the very next instruction. Or the kernel could have suspended your thread for some period of time on the `return` of this imaginary function.

Comment: @kfsone Got it. However, I am exploring the possibility to achieve this via any mechanism. Signals for example might be one i.e., receiving a signal when a blocking operation has occurred; similar to performing a timed context-switch upon receiving SIGPROF. So, regarding your valid point of getting the information accurately, it does not matter as long as I can detect the blocked operation/thread and execute a ready thread instead to achieve almost a full CPU quantum of the underlying kernel-thread. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be code that did this, for example [GNU pth](https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/). It's generally been abandoned because it just doesn't work very well and we have much better options now. You have two choices:

1) If you have OS help, you can use the OS mechanisms. Windows provides OS help for this, IOCP dispatching uses it.

2) If you have no OS help, then you have to convert all blocking operations into non-blocking ones that call your dispatcher rather than blocking. So, for example, if someone calls `socket`, you intercept that call and set the socket non-blocking. When they call `read`, you intercept that call and if they get a "would block" indication, you arrange to resume when the operation might succeed and schedule another thread.

You can look at GNU pth to see how you might make option 2 work. But be warned, GNU pth is [full of reported bugs](https://www.mail-archive.com/pth-users@gnu.org/msg00336.html) that have never been fixed since it was abandoned. It will give you an idea of how to implement things like mutexes and sleeps in a cooperative user-space threading environment. But don't actually use the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I first start looking into this I came across GNU pth. In addition to what you have pointed out, it also seems N:1 model where all user-level threads mapped and scheduled on one kernel-thread; without a facility to, for example, manually migrate a suspended thread to resume on another kernel-thread as per my requirment. However, pth can be configured to automatically map system calls (e.g., read) into pth library to generate non-blocking ones (or in other words, only block pth threads).

Comment: @TuaimiAA Yeah, you'd have to write what you want. It doesn't exist because experimentation has shown that it sucks. What's your use case? Why can't you do what everyone else does with similar use cases?

Comment: I need to execute tasks in multithreaded environment (pthreads). The tasks are basically user functions that might use blocking operations within and can be synchronized. I need to hide latency in my implementation. So, I am exploring the idea of implementing the tasks as user-level threads for a better control of their execution context such that, if a task blocks or synchronizes with others, I context-switch to other ready tasks. Consequently, almost full CPU quantum of the underlying kernel-thread can be achieved. As far as I know, similar use cases adopt similar concepts as this.

Comment: If you run each task in a separate pthread then the kernel will take care of context-switching to other ready tasks when one blocks.

Comment: @caf pthreads are heavyweight compared to user-level, and context switching is much more expensive.

Comment: Kernel context switching is actually very fast, particularly between two threads using the same mm (so they don't require a TLB flush).  You want to do this at the point where a thread is blocking, which requires a call into the kernel *anyway*, so you're already paying that overhead.

Comment: To put this another way: you're asking that when a thread goes to wait in the kernel, the kernel instead sets up a signal frame or similar and returns to userspace to execute that handler, from where you can switch user threads.  But that isn't going to be any faster than just letting the kernel directly switch to another pending thread in the same process and return to userspace.

Comment: @caf Thank for your valuable comments and the clarification. I have seen parallel execution models using similar approach (i.e., N:M) by letting waiting user-level threads context-switch instead of kernel switching. Considering situations in which million of tasks need to be executed, I do not think it is optimal to just launch kernel thread for each. However, if number of kernel threads (possibly equal to hardware threads/processors) are working on the tasks, I imagine this would prevent unnecessary kernel switching as kernel threads are scheduled preemptively.

Comment: If you have very large numbers of tasks that need to be executed, they should be sitting in some kind of passive structure (like a queue). They really shouldn't have things like stacks associated with them.

Comment: Look at how the Go language runtime does it. If I remember correctly it keeps a thread pool for doing system calls. That way it can keep its goroutine scheduler running goroutines even while waiting on something.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, tasks are pushed into a queue for execution. A task will be tied to the kernel thread that started its execution it if there is no stack associated with it.

Comment: @TuaimiAA In C++, you can do this nicely with Boost's coroutines.

Comment: If you don't want your runnable kernel threads to preempt each other, you can schedule them as `SCHED_FIFO` at the same static priority level - in that case a running thread will get to run until it blocks.

Comment: @caf Thank you for pointing this out. I will definitely test it.